# Using GSON to parse JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

How do I parse this JSON using the GSON Library.

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "None"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Burlesque"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Emo"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Goth"
}
]
```

I have tried to do this

```
public class EventEntity{

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;



    public String get_id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String get_title() {
        return this.title;
    }
}

JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(result);
            //JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
            Log.d("GetEventTypes", jArr.toString());                

            EventEntity[] enums = gson.fromJson(result, EventEntity[].class);
            for(int x = 0; x < enums.length; x++){                  
                String id = enums[x].get_id().toString();
            }
```

So far I can get the id using get_id method but I cant seem to assign it to the string id. What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: usually the get Methods do not have an underscore... it should be getId()/getTitle(). What do you mean by "get the id using get_id method but I cant seem to assign". Why not? Have you tried debugging or printing the id?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `EventEntity` is correct, but in order to parse the JSON, you'd better do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<EventEntity>>() {}.getType();
List<EventEntity> data = gson.fromJson(result, listType);
```

Then you'll have a `List` with all your `EventEntity` objects into the variable `data`, so you can access the values just with:

```
String id = data.get(i).get_id();
String title = data.get(i).get_title();
```

Comment: for some reason I can get the id but not the title

Comment: @GrayStatic, that's really weird... are you checking that the JSON into `result` before parsing is exactly as you described and has a field called exactly `"title"`?

Comment: yes there is, it is returned by the get method but not being passed to the string. Same problem I had earlier but now the id works fine.